# Gerrit resets gerrit.canonicalWebUrl o nevery restart

Tags: docker, gerrit

I installed a dockered gerrit instance.

Gerrit keeps resetting my canonicalWebUrl in gerrit.config on every restart. I executed reload-config / flush-caches. When I restart my docker container the file will be overwritten.

What am I missing here? Why does gerrit overwrite the config and where does it take the information from?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gerrit uses an environment variable to set the canonicalWebURL.

When you run your container add `-e CANONICAL_WEB_URL=http:\\gerrit.domain\r`, that should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I added the env to my docker compose and it works